# How to send value from suneditor textarea in php?

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, text-editor

I want to send textarea value in php  [Suneditor](https://github.com/JiHong88/SunEditor)

PHP code

```
if($_POST["submit"]){
    $content =  $_POST["txtEditor"];
    echo $content;
}
```

Html Code

```
 <form action="" method="post" >
        <textarea id="txtEditor" name="txtEditor" style="display:none;"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit">
    </form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtEditor").Editor();
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $('#txtEditor').val($('#txtEditor').Editor('getText'));
    });
    $('#txtEditor').Editor('setText', $('#txtEditor').val());
});

suneditor.create('txtEditor', {
    buttonList: [
        ['undo', 'redo', 'removeFormat'],
        [align, font, fontSize, fontColor, hiliteColor],
        [horizontalRule, image, template]
    ],
})
```

Editor working perfectly.
Where I did go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

full code

```
const description = SUNEDITOR.create((document.getElementById('description')),{
            buttonList: [
                ['undo', 'redo'],
                ['bold', 'underline', 'italic'],
                ['removeFormat'],
                ['outdent', 'indent'],
                ['align', 'list'],
                ['table'],
                ['fullScreen', 'showBlocks']
            ],
            lang: SUNEDITOR_LANG['pl']
        });
        $(window).click(function() {
            document.getElementById('description').value = description.getContents();
        });
```

Comment: you can't declare container variables as constants because constants don't change so assign var then it's working

Answer (score 1):

You just need to run the `instance.save()` method.

```
const instance = SUNEDITOR.create();
instance.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must send values from suneditor to textarea, you can do that:

```
$(window).click(function() {
            document.getElementById('txtEditor').value = txtEditor.getContents();
        });
```

Comment: txtEditor.getContents is not a function can u write full js code please

Answer (score 0):

You need isset function in if condition otherwise it will throw an error.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $content =  $_POST["txtEditor"];
    echo $content;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to write any js code for this, just put your text/content between textarea tag just like:

```
<textarea id="txtEditor" name="txtEditor" style="display:none;">Here is your text</textarea>
OR
<textarea id="txtEditor" name="txtEditor" style="display:none;">
   <?= $content; ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Gets the suneditor's context object. Contains settings, plugins, and cached element objects

editor.getContext();

// Gets the contents of the suneditor
// onlyContents {Boolean}: Return only the contents of the body without headers when the "fullPage" option is true

editor.getContents(onlyContents: Boolean);    

// Gets only the text of the suneditor contents

editor.getText();

// Change the contents of the suneditor
editor.setContents('set contents');
```